# SWIG - Como converter tipos primitivos que são passados por referência?

Tags: c#, c++

Estou utilizando o SWIG pra conseguir usar um código em C++ no C# (Ogre3D pros curiosos)
Tenho o seguinte método em C++:

```
bool suggestTangentVectorBuildParams(VertexElementSemantic targetSemantic,
            unsigned short& outSourceCoordSet, unsigned short& outIndex)
```

Porém o SWIG não consegue converter o tipo `unsigned short&`, então no C# fica assim:

```
public bool suggestTangentVectorBuildParams(VertexElementSemantic targetSemantic, 
                SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_short outSourceCoordSet, SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_short outIndex)
```

Onde está `SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_short` era pra ser `out ushort`.

Tentei mexer na interface do SWIG colocando esta linha pra tentar converter mas não funcionou, ainda continua `SWIGTYPE_p_unsigned_short`:

```
%typemap(cstype) unsigned short& "out ushort"
```

Onde estou errando?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de muita pesquisa e ajudinhas do paroj do [Ogre3D](https://www.ogre3d.org/), consegui!

O que eu fiz pra resolver foi o seguinte, usei o `%apply` e ficou assim:

```
%apply unsigned short& OUTPUT { unsigned short& outSourceCoordSet, unsigned short& outIndex };
```

Se alguém estiver passando pelo mesmo problema com o método `suggestTangentVectorBuildParams`, é só baixar a última versão do [repositório do Ogre](https://github.com/OGRECave/ogre), pois já foi corrigido com o pull request que fiz.